# jQuery.on() Delegation: Slightly complex selector for dynamically built HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Past few days I've been developing a commenting system UI using Quill and Github API and after the initial part's done (i.e. the comments loading) I'm working on the UI for the comments replies (also with Quill):

```js
// Quill Configuration

var quill = new Quill(
  '#comments .rich',
  {
    modules: {
      toolbar: {
        container: '#comments .toolbar'
      }
    },
    placeholder: '',
    theme: 'snow'
  }
);

// Anmated Show/Hide
  
$( '#comments .rich + .toggle' ).on( 'click', () => {
  $( '#comments .editor > div' ).removeClass( 'animated active' ).next().addClass( 'animated active' );
});


$( '#comments .markdown' ).siblings().find( '.toggle' ).on( 'click', () => {
  $( '#comments .editor > div' ).removeClass( 'animated active' ).prev().addClass( 'animated active' );
});
```

```css
:root {
  --animate-duration: 1s;
  --animate-delay: 1s;
  --animate-repeat: 1;
}

#comments .editor {
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

  #comments .editor.inline {
    margin-top: 1.3rem;
  }

  #comments .editor > div {
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
  }

  #comments .editor > div.active {
    left: 0;
  }

  #comments .rich {
    border-top: 0;
  }

  #comments .rich, #comments .markdown {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  #comments .editor a.toggle {
    border-radius: 5rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
    position: relative;
    width: max-content;
  }

    #comments .editor a:not(.toggle):hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

.animated {
  animation-duration: var(--animate-duration);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

  .animated.fadeInLeft {
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  }

  .animated.fadeInRight {
    animation-name: fadeInRight;
  }

@keyframes fadeInLeft {

  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d( -100%, 0, 0 );
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0 );
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {

  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d( 100%, 0, 0 );
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0 );
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comments">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row editor">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 fadeInLeft active">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-bold" title="Bold"></button>
          <button class="ql-italic" title="Italic"></button>
          <button class="ql-underline" title="Underline"></button>
          <button class="ql-strike" title="Strikethrough"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-link" title="Link"></button>
          <button class="ql-image" title="Images"></button>
          <button class="ql-video" title="Videos"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-blockquote" title="Quote"></button>
          <button class="ql-mention" title="Cite">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18">
              <circle class="ql-stroke" cx="9" cy="9" r="2"></circle>
              <path class="ql-stroke" d="M11,14.651A6,6,0,1,1,15,9a2,2,0,0,1-4,0V7" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="rich"></div>
      <a class="d-inline-flex justify-content-center mt-2 mb-2 ms-auto toggle">Markdown</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 fadeInRight">
      <textarea class="markdown"></textarea>
      <div class="d-flex align-content-center mt-2">
        <a href="/help#editor" class="me-auto">Help</a>
        <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center toggle">Rich Text</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

When someone clicks the "Reply" link present on each comment loaded from the Github API (here omitted), all HTML of `.editor` is duplicated below the said link. I then instantiate a new Quill object for that newly added selector (also omitted) and everything is ready to use.

However, I came to a deadlock regarding the animation that shows/hides the Rich Text/Markdown Editors, **specifically, but not limited to**, the link that hides the Markdown and shows the Rich Text.

As you can see in this code, I had to wrap the two links in a `<div>` to position them one to the left and the other to the right in order to provide the visitors help regarding the usage of Markdown (after all, that's how I met and learned it in the past) and, currently, I had to use `jQuery.siblings()` to reach the toggler link and then bind the *click* handler to it.

But since all comments are loaded by an AJAX Request to Github API, their markup don't exist in the DOM yet and, therefore, I have to delegate using `jQuery.on()` second argument:

```
$( '#comments' ).on( 'click', '.comments .rich + .toggle', function() {});
```

> Which, in fact, actually works to hide the Rich Text and show the Markdown

But so far I've been unable to adapt the second animation selection to the delegation syntax to hide the Markdown and show the Rich Text once again.

> If there's a better way to do the HTML in order to simplify the JS (both animations), I'm all ears ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two event handler for same task you can combine them . So ,whenever your `toggle` element gets clicked you can check if the `.data('text')` is `Markdown` or not depending on this you change your selector i.e : *prev()* or *next()*

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var quill = new Quill(
  '#comments .rich', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: {
        container: '#comments .toolbar'
      }
    },
    placeholder: '',
    theme: 'snow'
  }
);
//when any toggle elemnt is click
$(document).on("click", "#comments > .editor a.toggle", function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest(".active").removeClass('animated active') //get closest div with active class
  //depending on text..
  $(this).data('text').trim() == "Markdown" ? selector.next().addClass('animated active') : selector.prev().addClass('animated active') //add/remove

})
```

```css
:root {
  --animate-duration: 1s;
  --animate-delay: 1s;
  --animate-repeat: 1;
}

#comments .editor {
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#comments .editor.inline {
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
}

#comments .editor>div {
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}

#comments .editor>div.active {
  left: 0;
}

#comments .rich {
  border-top: 0;
}

#comments .rich,
#comments .markdown {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#comments .editor a.toggle {
  border-radius: 5rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

#comments .editor a:not(.toggle):hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: var(--animate-duration);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.fadeInLeft {
  animation-name: fadeInLeft;
}

.animated.fadeInRight {
  animation-name: fadeInRight;
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d( -100%, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d( 100%, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="comments">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row editor">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 fadeInLeft active">
      <div class="toolbar">
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-bold" title="Bold"></button>
          <button class="ql-italic" title="Italic"></button>
          <button class="ql-underline" title="Underline"></button>
          <button class="ql-strike" title="Strikethrough"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-link" title="Link"></button>
          <button class="ql-image" title="Images"></button>
          <button class="ql-video" title="Videos"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
          <button class="ql-blockquote" title="Quote"></button>
          <button class="ql-mention" title="Cite">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 18 18">
              <circle class="ql-stroke" cx="9" cy="9" r="2"></circle>
              <path class="ql-stroke" d="M11,14.651A6,6,0,1,1,15,9a2,2,0,0,1-4,0V7" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="rich"></div>
      <!--added data-attr-->
      <a class="d-inline-flex justify-content-center mt-2 mb-2 ms-auto toggle" data-text="Markdown">Markdown</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 fadeInRight">
      <textarea class="markdown"></textarea>
      <div class="d-flex align-content-center mt-2">
        <a href="/help#editor" class="me-auto">Help</a>
        <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center toggle" data-text="Rich">Rich Text</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With a minor adjustment, changing `document` for `#comments` and removing `#comments >` in jQuery.on() delegation selector, I can show/hide both the main editors as well as the dynamically loaded ones. By itself, that solves my problem, however, that approach has the problem of a hard-coded text, if, in the future, I want to make some sort of localization it would stop working. Anything to workaround that? Something clean, without, for example, setting a *data attribute* to be read or anything like it. In any event, thank you for your time